# Anaconda and miniconda : Conflict in using jupyter notebook or pycharm?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, miniconda

I'm new to the programming environments.
Last year, I had a course where we installed (without understanding what we were doing) miniconda with python 3.7 and jupyter notebook. This year I need anaconda so I installed it with the latest version of python. My question is: will there be a conflict between anaconda and miniconda if I use the shell commands? When I type "jupyter notebook" in the shell, will it open with miniconda which I installed first or anaconda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on a linux system?
You can try with

```
type jupyter-notebook
```

This will show you where the binary is located. For example ~/miniconda3/bin.
The path of the bin-folder of your anaconda/miniconda installation is usually added to your path-variable in the ~/.bashrc file.

PS:
You can find out which version of python/python3 you are using by typing

```
python --version
```

or

```
python3 --version
```

Comment: Ohhh thanks for the hint it gave me .../anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook so I guess it's used with anaconda. Can you tell how should I proceed if I ever wanted to use jupyter notebook with miniconda what should I do ?

Comment: Having just one of the two installed should usually be sufficient. You can always install new conda / python packages with "conda  install", "pip install", "pip3 install". However, if you wish to switch enviroment, you should be able to do that by editing the paths in the .bashrc file in your home-directory and reopening your terminal window. You can also start jupyter-notebook by "~/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", but I am not completely sure in which python enviroment it will run.